# How can I sparse checkout a subdirectory from git without checking out its parent directories?

Tags: git, subdirectory, git-checkout, sparse-checkout, git-sparse-checkout

I am trying to sparse-checkout a subdirectory from my git repository.

The repository contains multiple plugins for wordpress and I want to check them out one by one. With the below posted solutions I have encountered the problem that EVERYTIME I check out the parent directory of the subdirectory is also checked out and the plugins are not working.

I tried something like this [Is it possible to do a sparse checkout without checking out the whole repository first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository) and something like that [Git sparse checkout for simple web deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827117/git-sparse-checkout-for-simple-web-deployment) .

I really hope somebody can help me because I just feel like I kind of missed some information.

Thank you.

Comment: You said you tried to follow those other answers.  Did they work? Did they not work? What happened?

Comment: They did not work. I just wanted to checkout the subdirectory without any parent directories, so I set the options in the sparse-checkout file like suggested in the links I posted. What happened was, that when I wanted to checkout for example subdirectory 2 from the following structure:
[Parent] > [subdirectory 1], [subdirectory 2] the parent folder was checked out also and I couldn't use it in the wordpress plugins folder.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository

Comment: So finally were you able to checkout subdirectory without its parent directory, I am also stuck in same problem. Please help me if you have found the solution